# Dagger 2 Android is not injecting field

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to create ma first Android Dagger app.
I've read some tutorials and now I'm trying to make it work.
The problem is, when i call settings.get() in MainActivity, i'm getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object javax.inject.Provider.get()' on a null object reference
    at biz.golek.whattodofordinner.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:57)
```

which is:
**settings.get().Run();**

I've created:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    Provider<ShowSettingsController> settings;

    /.../

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            settings.get().Run();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

App:

```
public class WhatToDoForDinnerApp extends com.orm.SugarApp {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityInjector());
    }
```

}

ActivityInjector:

```
public class ActivityInjector implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    private ApplicationComponent component;

    public ActivityInjector(){
        this.component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .settingsModule(new SettingsModule())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)       {
        component.inject(activity);
    }

    /.../
}
```

ApplicationComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { SettingsModule.class })
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(Activity activity);
}
```

And SettingsModule:

```
@Module
public class SettingsModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    static ShowSettingsController provideShowSettingsController(){
        return new ShowSettingsControllerImpl();
    }

    /.../
}
```

The whole code is at my github at: [whattodofordinner](https://github.com/bartoszgolek/whattodofordinner)
Aby ideas what I have wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am just learning dagger 2, but I think you need a component for your settings module. This tutorial helped me: https://blog.gouline.net/2015/05/04/dagger-2-even-sharper-less-square/

Answer (score 1):

I think in your `ApplicationComponent` you have to define a `inject`-Method for each Activity. It is not possible to use composition.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { SettingsModule.class })
public interface ApplicationComponent {
   void inject(MainActivity activity);
   void inject(AnotherActivity activity);
}
```

**Edit 04.02.16:**

Furthermore, your provides-method is static declared. Try to remove that static.

```
@Module
public class SettingsModule {

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   ShowSettingsController provideShowSettingsController(){
      return new ShowSettingsControllerImpl();
   }

   /.../
}
```

You may also declare a provides statement within your ApplicationComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { SettingsModule.class })
public interface ApplicationComponent {

   SettingsController settingsController();

   void inject(MainActivity activity);
   void inject(AnotherActivity activity);
}
```

Comment: I've checked. Still not working. I added just to check cast to MainActivity in ActivityInjector.onActivityCreated and changed signature if inject to MainActivity.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuilt your project? I'm sorry, I do not have any further idea.

Comment: Yes, I did. Did'nt help too.

Comment: @BartoszGołek: Please try to remove the static keyword from the provides-Method. See my updated answer.

Comment: I found other solution, but acording to dagger users guide provider method can be static: [link](http://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html).

See Satisfying Dependencies section examples.
Great thanks for Your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing the SettingsModule in your ApplicationComponent. If you do want the settings module to be available in the scope of the whole application then add it to the modules list like this:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AppModule.class, SettingsModule.class })
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(Activity activity);
}
```

Your ActivityInjector would also have to be updated like so:

```
public class ActivityInjector implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
private ApplicationComponent component;

public ActivityInjector(){
    this.component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule())
            .settingsModule(new SettingsModule())
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)       {
    component.inject(activity);
}

/.../
```

Comment: I cleared code before posting and it looks i remove the module by mistake. I've fixed it in question.

Comment: You should probably make it clear you've edited your question with the correct answer otherwise it could be confusing to anyone that comes along.

Comment: Provider is to avoid holding reference dureing whole life of application, and lazy initialization. As I read its part of Dagger.

Comment: I did not realise thanks for letting me know. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Actually for Lazy initilization you should use Lazy<ShowSettingsController> settings according to the Dagger 2 site.

Comment: Provider is used to return multiple instances instead of injecting a single value.

Comment: Yes, im aware of that, and Provider is exactly what I want. When main activity is instantiated, there is no need for instantiate Settings controller. And then if it is not used then should be collected by garbage collector.

When I call Settings again i'll call get again and Dagger will create new instance of Controller and its dependencies. And then only container is responsible for decision that controller is singleinstance or multiple. Not the implementation of class which using it.

Answer (score 0):

I've finnaly got this to work. Dont know why, but Dagger did'nt want to inject dependencies by field, but works perfectly using constructor. IMO using constructor is even better (dependencies are shown explicit by constructor parameters), so I've changed my classes to use injected constructor.

Second thing is how to put dependencies to Activity without making it aware of container (component).

I made it by defining IAware interface:

```
public interface IAware<T> {
    void Set(T item);
}
```

And then marker interface IControllersProviderAware:

```
public interface IControllersProviderAware extends IAware<ControllersProvider> {
}
```

The ControllersProvider class is also not aware of container, it is aware only of javax.inject, due to using Provider class, but it is generic and not dependant of Dagger (container specific implementation):

```
public class ControllersProvider {
    private final Provider<ShowSettingsController> showSettingsControllerProvider;

    public ControllersProvider(Provider<ShowSettingsController> showSettingsControllerProvider)
    {
        this.showSettingsControllerProvider = showSettingsControllerProvider;
    }

    public ShowSettingsController getShowSettingsController() {
        return showSettingsControllerProvider.get();
    }
}
```

Last thing to do was implementation of ControllersProviderInjector which is responsible for setting ControllersProvider to the activity if activity is aware of ControllersProvider:

```
    public class ControllersProviderInjector implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    private ControllersProvider controllersProvider;

    @Inject
    public ControllersProviderInjector(ControllersProvider controllersProvider) {
        this.controllersProvider = controllersProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (activity instanceof IControllersProviderAware)
            ((IControllersProviderAware)activity).Set(controllersProvider);
    }
}
```

Everythig is registered in module:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    static ControllersProvider provideControllersProvider(
            Provider<ShowSettingsController> showSettingsControllerProvider
    ){
        return new ControllersProvider(
            showSettingsControllerProvider
        );
    }
}
```

And finally the implementation of Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IControllersProviderAware {

    private ControllersProvider controllerProvider;

    /.../

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            this.controllerProvider.getShowSettingsController().Run();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void Set(ControllersProvider item) {
        this.controllerProvider = item;
    }
}
```

The main advantage of doing this 'complications' instead of adding getComponent method to App, and using it from onCreate of Activity as shown [here](https://blog.gouline.net/2015/05/04/dagger-2-even-sharper-less-square/), is the independance of business logic from container specifics. When there will be any better container than dagger, to change it i can simply change my implementation of ControllersProvider and container specific stuff.

Everything is of course on my github: https://github.com/bartoszgolek/whattodofordinner

Thanks for help for everyone and hope You'll enjoy my work.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked up at your project on github and noticed some misunderstanding of using dagger framework. I made several fixes and dependencies injected fine.

First of all you need to make your dependency graph to be available for other app components.

```
public class WhatToDoForDinnerApp extends com.orm.SugarApp {
    private ApplicationComponent component;

    public ApplicationComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule())
            .settingsModule(new SettingsModule())
            .addNewDinnerModule(new AddNewDinnerModule())
            .build();
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you need to tell dagger what class is expecting for injection.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, SettingsModule.class, AddNewDinnerModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    ViewStateManager viewStateManager();
    ControllersProviderInjector controllersProviderInjector();

    void inject(MainActivity activity); //now you are able to inject dependencies in your MainActivity
}
```

And finally you need to inject what you need. In this case you can inject all items which are provided by all modules (`AppModule`, `SettingsModule`, `AddNewDinnerModule`) declared in `ApplicationComponent`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private View.OnClickListener listener;

@Inject
Provider<ShowSettingsController> showSettingsController;
@Inject
Provider<AddNewDinnerController> newDinnerController;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((WhatToDoForDinnerApp) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this); //at this moment your dependencies are injected

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(...);

    listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            newDinnerController.get().Run();
        }
    };
}
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ...
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        showSettingsController.get().Run();
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,
What worries me at this solution is, all activiteis are aware of component. And component is dagger specific. It strongly bonds me with Dagger.

Second thing is the requirement method for every activity I want to be injected.


As I wrote in my answer, I've found solution, which is free of this inconveniencess. It still have some inconveniencess like adding method for every controller to controllerProvider, but controllers are entry points to bussiness logic, so IMO it is less harmfull

Comment: yeap I got it, I mean your code looks like it doesn't really need Dagger, but in case if you would like to use it you probably should learn more about building dependency graph with dagger, for example there is great tutorial (sources with several articles):
https://github.com/frogermcs/GithubClient

Comment: It is not like "it doesn't realy need', its more like 'using something but, not to be bound. It is in case when, maybe in some time, there'll be bettter solution than Dagger2, or it w'll be Dagger3. And tehn I dont want to change all my Activities.

Again thaks for Your help.